# How to force component render in React

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, reactive-programming, flux

I am making a simple ajax call to an API that produces data every 5 seconds, the data is received correctly using observables, and the data state is updated as expected.
the problem is: the page is rendering only once when it is loaded, and not when date is changed using the setData function. if I reload the page by navigating to another link and then come back the data shows as expected
her is the code:

```
function MyComponent() {

   const [data, setData] = useState(RxJSStore.getData())

   useEffect(() => {
       RxJSStore.addChangeListener(onChange);
       if (data.length === 0) loadDataRxJSAction()
       return () => RxJSStore.removeChangeListener(onChange)
   }, [data.length])


   function onChange() {
       setData(RxJSStore.getData())
   }

   return (
       <>
            <List data={data} />

       </>
   )
}
```

Comment: are you sure the length of the data change ?
Also, i don't think it's good practice to launch an async call in the default value on the useState

Comment: thnx Dario, yes the lenght of the data array is changing every time I receive a new response from my ajax call (the state is updated in the store then it is received in the component since I have onChange() which will update the data array)   so the data array is updated correctly

Comment: Could you provide a code sandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-wescoff-sxbwx?file=/src/warningsActions.js

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a check tomorrow in the morning, i'll have to go

Comment: Where is `onChange` being used?

Comment: Your codesandbox is incomplete and not runnable. Why are you duplicating state? You should have a single source of truth.

Comment: @Drew Reese where do you mean I am duplicating the sate? I am kind of new to the approach

Comment: You are duplicating your store into local component state, which invariably leads to synchronization issues with the duplicated local state.

Comment: but I need to watch for any changes in the store, so that I can render my component based on the changes. do you mean I should not use the use state at all ?

Comment: @ Ross Allen I have updated the code so you can see the entire data flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way around this by forcing the component to render every time the onChange method is called. It is written in the documentation that this must only be used for testing purposes, but as the situation does not have another solution this might be the solution for this use case.

```
import { useRefresh } from 'react-tidy'

 function MyComponent() {

 const [data, setData] = useState(RxJSStore.getData())
const refresh = useRefresh()

useEffect(() => {
   RxJSStore.addChangeListener(onChange);
   if (data.length === 0) loadDataRxJSAction()
   return () => RxJSStore.removeChangeListener(onChange)
}, [data.length])


  function onChange() {
    setWarnings(RxJSStore.getWarnings())
    refresh()
}

return (
   <>
        <List data={data} />

   </>
 )
}
```